# SyliusAttributeBundle getProduct()

Tags: symfony, sylius

I've just face a problem with the relationship between my product entity and attribute.

When I try to add a attribute to my product, I get an error message saying that `getProduct` method doesn't exist...

So after digging and digging... I found a solution : I have to override the `addAttribute` method of the product entity and change `$attribut->getProduct()` to `$attribut->getSubject()`

So, now it's working but I think I've still missed something...

Have you an idea why I need to override this method ?

Thx!

Comment: So is your product an instance of a custom product class, `Sylius\Component\Core\Product` or `Sylius\Component\Product\Product` ? Are you using the full Sylius app, or just a few of its bundles/components?

Comment: i'm using a few of its bundles ( cart, order, product, ressources ). An i have created my own product class who extends the one form the product bundle.